# Variable output result in unintended result

Tags: python, variables

I am having a challenge to understand my own code:

My challange:

As a result of the current code (it is not finished) variable `varA = 3`
I would expect `varA` to stay unchanged `0`.

My question:

Can somebody explain to me why `varA` is changing?
aka which part of the code makes `varA` change?

```
# base variables
listA = [0,1,3,0,1,3]
listA_max = max(listA)
listA_min = min(listA)
# length of listA
listALen = len(listA)

varA = min(listA)
listB = []
# for check: append varA if not in listA
listC = []

# index no listA
listA_i = 0

print ('checks')
print ('listA_min =' + str(listA_min))
print ('listA_max =' + str(listA_max))
print ('varA = ' + str(varA))
print (' ')

while listA_i < listALen and varA <= listA_max:
    for varA in listA:
        if varA == listA[listA_i]:
            listB.append(varA)
    else:
        break

print (' ')
print ('results ')
print ('varA = ' + str(varA))
print ('listA_i = ' + str(listA_i))
print ('listB = ' + str(listB))
```

Comment: It's recommended to use another name in `for varA in listA:` other than varA. It will change your varA value

Comment: Wall of code, not sure what you try to do and where your problem is.  Why do you use a WHILE loop with some kind of index `listA_i`  that you never increase - and what should the else:break accomplish.

Comment: Because `for varA in listA`.

Comment: @ suneha  &  @ martineau
I think I am misunderstanding your solution; After renaming varA (to varAaA or varXYZ) the result is the same.

I will try ad an other variable (example: keep varA, ad varAaA, swap varA for varAaA in "for varA in list"

Comment: @ Patrick
why break? There was some code there, only it looped (unintended). So I used break to get aroud it (solve it later)

my goal:

Comment: Goal
check for each instance of 'listA' if 'value listA instandce' equals  'varA'
if so; append current value of 'varA' to 'listB'


What I'am trying to get the code to do:
1. take the minimum value of listA
2. make this value 'varA'

3.1 compaire 'varA' to  all list instances
start comparing 'varA' with 'list index 0' 
3.1.1 while doing this: if 'varA' == listB[index] append the current value of 'varA' to listB

4.1   reasign value 'varA' to 'varA + 1'
4.1.1 if 'varA' <= 'max value of listA' return to step 3.1
4.1.2 if 'varA' > 'max value of listA' break

Comment: expected output of 'listB' after runnen code                    [0,0,1,1,2,2]
expected output of 'listB' after running 'varA = 0' & 'varA =1' [0,0,1,1]

Comment: I know this is not the most effective way.
I want to do it this way to get an better understanding of: How to talk to Python?

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```py
for varA in listA:
    if varA == listA[listA_i]:
        listB.append(varA)
```

You are iterating through `listA` setting `varA` each time. So when you finish iterating, `varA` will hold the last value of `listA`, in this case, 3. If you don't want this to happen, then change the name of the variable in the `for` loop to something else.

```py
for num in listA:
    if num == listA[listA_i]:
        listB.append(num)
```

Comment: Thank you, Safwan.
You explained to me where my thoughs went wrong.
One step closer to understand Python. 
Enjoy

Comment: If it's correct and you accept it, press the grey tick next to the question, indicating that it is the correct answer.